# Python: module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'orc'

Tags: python, pyarrow

I have installed `pyarrow` trough `pip`

```
pip install pyarrow

import pyarrow as pya
```

if I call the attribute `orc` I get the following error

```
pya.orc
AttributeError: module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'orc'
```

Answer (score 5):

With a Conda installed pyarrow, I had to explicitly

```py
import pyarrow.orc
```

to avoid the error you got.

Answer (score 3):

The pyarrow wheels (which are used when installing with `pip`) do not include ORC bindings, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-7811.

If you want to use ORC, you need to install pyarrow using `conda` instead (or manually from source), for now.

See the installation guidelines: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/install.html